# Magento 1.8.1 login only refreshes

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, login, cookie

Yesterday I messed something up on my Magento installation. A plugin destroyed the test environment, so I've decided to reïnstall the test environment.

I got the back-up database from our working live site, as well as the map structure. 
Put everything in place in the local HtDocs folder and changed the database url's and the local.xms file to the appropriate parameters.

Everything seems to work, however when I go to the back-end and log in... it just refreshes and does nothing.

I have read a lot about restoring cookies and editing the varien file. 
`/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php`

However, this does not work. 
So far I've tried:

changing the web/cookies url's in the database;

clearing the `var/cache` folder;

clearing the browser cookies and cache;

edit the `varien.php` file.

It doesn't seem to work, the front end works fine.

Comment: Did you clean session in `/var/sessions`? Are you sure your `/app/etc/local.xml` points to the right palce for your admin?

Comment: It appears my Magento installation doesn't have a `/var/sessions` folder. I am sure the `/app/etc/local.xml` file points to the right place.

Comment: it's `/var/session` my bad. Do you have any error in your Apache logs? or in Magento logs for that instance.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's `/var/session` or `/var/sessions` I haven't got either =). There are no error logs from Magento or Apache.

Comment: are you sure your `local.xml` points to the right place and that it points to the right database?

Comment: Yes, it uses an IP adres to the computer that hosts the local testserver. And the user: root / root. Now I've added a new user, changed the xml file. It still refreshes.

Comment: are you using some caching system? (Memcached, Varnish ...etc)
did you try changing browser to see if it wasn't browser-cache related?

Comment: local.xml has `<backend>memcached</backend><memcached><servers><server><host>192.168.28.22/grayle.com</host><persistent>0</persistent><port>0</port></server></servers></memcached>` I have used 5 different browsers, the same thing happens in every browser. I have cleared the browser cache many times and the local cookies as well.

Comment: restart memcached and empty it, or the other way around.

Comment: Memcache is turned off on the local server. I removed the specifications for it in the .xml file. Doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I have checked the system.log. These two errors came up: 1. `2014-08-05T07:28:26+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: type_product  in C:\xampp\htdocs\grayle.com\app\code\local\Magentothem\Ajaxcartsuper\controllers\AjaxcartController.php on line 25` and 2. `2014-08-04T14:56:54+00:00 DEBUG (7): array_combine() [<a href='function.array-combine'>function.array-combine</a>]: Both parameters should have at least 1 element/home/users/graylftp/grayle.com/includes/src/Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule.php` both look like they have nothing to do with the login...

Comment: indeed nothing to do with admin.

Comment: I'm at a loss at what is causing the problem...

Comment: I'm currently running out of ideas aswell

Comment: Have you read this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel/26164#26164 ?

Answer (score 3):

It's working for me.. Please follow below instruction

> Goto System->Configuration->Web->Session Cookie Management
>
> > change the option 'Use HTTP only' to 'No'
> >     [image]

Answer (score 2):

I would guess this is to do with the cookie domain you have set up, not being correct in your new development environment, OR, matching one that you're also using (if you have multiple Magento installations set up)

Check the `core_config_data` table and the entry with a path of `web/cookie/cookie_domain`.  Try clearing this, and then clear your browser cache and try logging in again.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem and simple trick worked for me. Also this is for people who cannot access the dashboard on **Google Chrome**. If you can carry on by working on Mozilla Firefox then please do so because I guess this issue is not persistent on Mozilla firefox.

So the solution for chrome is:

Goto **System->Configuration->Web**. Expand the **Unsecure and Secure** tab. Change the Base URL to `http://127.0.0.1/[Your folder name]` if your using localhost or change it to your Site URL through which you are accessing the frontend. I had to **login twice** to get the Dashboard since when I entered the details for the first time, it just refreshes and comes back to the same page as you mentioned it as looping. Please try and let me know whether it worked for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem, but in a different scenario. I had a working, live Magento install that one morning I suddenly wouldn't let me log in to the admin. It did what you described when I tried to log in - just reloaded. It turned out to be a disc quota issue.

**Solution**

We upped the available space and everything was right again. Check with your hosting to make sure you've got enough disc space, bandwith, etc and that nothing is over the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in `core_config_data` if the value of `web/cookie/force_secure_cookie` is set to 0.

When you restore a backup from a secure domain (https) to an unsecure (http) domain, this setting might be set to 1, which won't work on a unsecure domain.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried below ? Every ever new installation I faced same problem and it worked like charm

I think there is the problem with session cookie with the chrome browser. So just go through this directory /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php file and comment out the line from 85 to 92 in magento (1.7.2 for my case). Like this

```
  // session cookie params
   /* $cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
        'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );
  */
```

after that try to make login from your backend. Hopefully you can make login with chrome. This will definitely help you. If you are still facing the problem then just reply me.

Comment: I see this solution a lot on the web. This is wrong. Even if apparently fixed the problem, it doesn't. It just hides the dirt under the rug. You should not edit core code. And that code is there for a reason. You should not remove it. For sure there is an other solution.