# Login Loop in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I'm getting the infamous login loop in a fresh 1.9 install

The install is on a vagrant machine and it is accessed via the url: http://magento9.local locally.

I have cleared /var and cookies numerous times, reset all my permissions numerous times, its a clean install, theres no modules, i even tried the core file hacks (basically everything in this thread [Magento 1.9 Can’t login to admin panel!](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel))

I destroyed the instance and started again, and still can't get past the log in,

Home page works fine. n98-magerun

Magento was intsalled via

I am completely at a loss

Comment: Would I be correct therefore to assume, if you are using file based sessions, you have checked the disk is not at capacity or you are out of inodes (so sessions files can actually be created)?

Comment: @JonathanHussey session files are being created in var/sessions fine. So storage also isn't the issue

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification.  Have you tried the same fileset and database on another server instance (if practical)?

Comment: I will try that i guess, just a huge time sink aha!

Comment: Indeed, would just enable you to hopefully rule out some server configuration issue.  Alternatively try running another Magento instance you know to be working elsewhere on the server instance you are having trouble logging in to and see if you then have the same issues.

Comment: Have you really verified the vagrant instance timezone?

Comment: @Melvyn ran 'date' inside vagrant ssh, matches my local pc time? or is there another thing needed

Comment: It matches the clock, sure, but is the timezone correct as well?

Comment: @Melvyn Tue Nov 11 18:28:29 UTC 2014 from date. I am GMT so that would be correct

Comment: Ok, simple test to rule out other timezone issues: `curl -D /dev/stdout -o /dev/null --silent http://magento9.local/`. There should be a SetCookie header with cookiename frontend. What is the expire part?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have specified a cookie domain name that is relative to your environment or the cookie cannot be set. `admin->system->configuration->web->cookie domain` You should also try and clear your browsers cache and cookies to ensure such as well. Some instances I've seen leaving the domain blank will work as well but most likely falls back to PHP internal functions to determine the domain to attempt to set when writing the cookie.

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cookie.php#L101

It appears there is an exception in Core as well during session handling that simply throws an empty exception in a condition of validation of the session.

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php#L351

Which may explain the redirect to the login afterwards with no indication of why.

You can validate this as well with viewing the cookies in the browser to determine if an `adminhtml` or `frontend` cookie is being set. As well as attempting to login to the customer side.

Also, as Alan mentioned in the linked article:

> You're using the localhost as your server domain, and using a version
>   of webkit that has trouble/bugs setting cookies for localhost in some
>   situations.

domain.local may not be a valid TLD for your OS/Browser, Personally this is why I always map my local environments as simply `local.domain.com` to prevent any issues as such, as well as a lot of 3rd party modules validate domain names for licensing, this helps ease this problem as well.