# Can't login to Magento admin using Vagrant box

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, login, session, cookie

I'm trying to set up a local dev environment using Vagrant and the [Vaprobash](https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash) script since I've used it before in several PHP based applications but for some reason I'm not able to login to the admin area.

I'm using this [Vagrantfile](https://gist.github.com/jahvi/b8fa9ea87ca1e00dc2f0) and [my fork of Vaprobash](https://github.com/jahvi/Vaprobash) which only changes the nginx repo to use the 1.7 version so I end up with:

- Nginx 1.7
- PHP 5.5
- MySQL 5.6

Which should be fine considering the [system requirements for Magento 1.9](http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements).

I think it might be related to this [answer in SO](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/26083) however I've tried several ways to fix it without luck:

- I tried using Apache 2.2 instead of Nginx.
- I'm **not** using *localhost* or any other one-word domain name, I tried using the IP of the virtual box and also mapped a `magento.local.dev` domain in my hosts file.
- I tried storing sessions in files and database, both are getting stored just fine so it doesn't seem like a permissions issue.
- I tried commention out the `$cookieParams` lines in the `Varien.php` file and it didn't work so it might not be related to the cookies.
- I tried running the installer from the web interface, command line and the magerun script.
- I ran the magerun `sys:check` command and everything returned green.

There was a moment where I could make it work but I'm not exactly sure what I did because I was trying so many things, I remember opening incognito mode in Chrome, clearing the cookies and login in just fine but I destroyed the box to se if I could reproduce it and I couldn't.

I've managed to set it up using a [much simpler script](https://github.com/r-baker/simple-magento-vagrant) however I'm not sure what the difference might be, maybe it's because I'm using php-fpm but I've seen it work with Magento before. I'm thinking it might be some server setting or something like that but I can't see what it might be.

EDIT: I just noticed I can't add products to the shopping cart from the frontend, it could be part of the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a cookie issue to me. Can you check what are values for `web/cookie/cookie_path` and `web/cookie/cookie_domain` in `core_config_data table`.

Try setting them to NULL and see if it works.

Comment: They are both set to NULL, I tried changing the path to "/" and domain to ".magento.local.dev", cleared the cache and browser cookies but still no luck

Comment: I'll give it another tough but I am lost. I see you did you research so if you find what it was let us know please.

Comment: Yes it's really weird, hopefully someone can replicate it on their end to see if it's just me or the actual Vagrant script

Comment: I've set up a box using your [Vagrantfile](https://gist.github.com/jahvi/b8fa9ea87ca1e00dc2f0) with everything on default settings. I had no issues logging into admin.

Comment: Strange, what URL did you use? Did you use the default virtual host with the document root in the `/vagrant` folder? Also how did you install Magento?

Comment: local.dev. Magento was in vagrant/magento, default vhost, I just changed root folder. Installed using web installer.

Comment: That's weird I wonder if it's a timezone issue then

Comment: I created a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 box and installed a LEMP stack by myself and it worked so maybe my host OS doesn't like the Vagrantfile for some reason

Comment: Finally I found that using the default php packages from the ubuntu repos instead of the `ondrej/php5` one fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Case, that you dont see any cookie named `frontend` or `adminhtml`, when you reload the page, the Magento cookie wasn't set. In my case I have a wrong `cookie_domain`. I used `null` instead of `NULL`.

As I set my `cookie_domain` to `NULL` in `core_config_data`, the problem was solved.