# Base url issues which sometimes doesn't allow me to login in admin panel

Tags: login, admin-panel

[Following the explanation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel/26083?noredirect=1#comment74889_26083), I run the suggested command n98-magerun.phar sys:check

- Invalid Unsecure BaseURL Store: default Wrong hostname configured. Hostname must contain a dot
- Invalid Unsecure BaseURL Store: french Wrong hostname configured. Hostname must contain a dot
- Invalid Unsecure BaseURL Store: sot_eng Wrong hostname configured. Hostname must contain a dot
- Invalid Unsecure BaseURL Store: sot_fra Wrong hostname configured. Hostname must contain a dot
- Cookie Domain (secure) of Store: default OK - No domain set
- Cookie Domain (secure) of Store: french OK - No domain set
- Cookie Domain (secure) of Store: sot_eng OK - No domain set
- Cookie Domain (secure) of Store: sot_fra OK - No domain set

Comment: Please explain what do you mean when you say that admin panel doesn't allow you to log in and provide values of mentioned hostname fields.

Comment: @WojtekNaruniec When I try to login in admin the page refreshes and that’s all. No error or any other messages. After I clear cookies in browser I am able to login. This happens in Firefox and in Chrome as well

Answer (score 1):

Magento base url needs to contain a dot in order for the cookies to be propperly stored. I assume you are running the store in your local environment and use  `localhost` as the domain name. Try using local IP instead.

For example, if your website is linked to `http://localhost/` you should link it to: `http://127.0.0.1/`

Comment: No, this is not on my local environment. All my base urls look like: http://abc.xxx-demo.com/