# Customer Login Doesn't Work in 1.9.1.1

Tags: magento-1.9.1.1

I just did a fresh installation of Magento 1.9.0.1 and I am seeing some very odd behavior with the customer login form.

In Chrome (version 36) the login form does not work. I am just redirected to the login page. There is no error message. However, when I open a new Incognito Window, I am able to login just fine. Thinking this was a cookie problem, I cleared out all my cookies from the browser and tried again and I got the same results. In both cases, I am able to login to the admin panel without any issues.

I have also tried this in Firefox . On Firefox its work properly ..
thank you

Comment: are using url to your local as localhost ?

Comment: Try this `http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel`

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you dont have SSL for your website, make sure you have these settings for your magento setup:

Go to **System** > **Configuration** and select **Web** tab.
Under **Session & Cookie Management** tab, select

***Use HTTP Only***: YES

***Cookie Restriction Mode***: NO

***Cookie Lifetime***: 86450

Rest of the fields can be left as blank.