# Unable to login to magento admin in google chrom

Tags: magento-1.9

i am using magento 1.9.2.1 , but i am unable to login to admin using google chrome browser where as login works fine in firefox browser ,

Please guide me how to fix ,

1: in chrome when i enter wrong password i get error but for correct login details now error just admin login page reloads

2: please tell what to do to fix it

3: i have cleared cache many time and issue is on server only

in chrom after login url is like below

```
abc.ocm/index.php/admin/index/index/key/we1**************************/
```

Comment: Please clear your cookies, browsercache, etc and try again

Comment: have you installed on Ip address or on localhost?

Comment: Hi go to system -> configuration -> in left general menu -> web -> Session and cookie management->set yes http only

Comment: i had alreay set it

Comment: also my website is on subdmoain can this be issue

Comment: sorry set no and clear your cache mng then check

Answer (score 2):

This is a well known old issue which exist in Magento. However there is no single, elegant solution for this.

[**Refer this Thread**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel) and see [**Alanstorm**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/4/alan-storm)'s answer. There is nothing more I can say about this issue. Here I am quoting the possible reasons for this issue

> Possible causes include
>
> - Local computer time vs. server time mismatch, causing instant cookie
>     invalidation. Make sure your server time is correct.
> - Incorrect permissions on var/session, preventing session files from
>     being saved
> - Incorrect configuration of database/redis/other session storage,
>     preventing saving of session values
> - A module is instantiating sessions to early, preventing the correct
>     session names from being set
> - You're a developer using multiple URLs and have multiple cookie
>     domains
> - Another developer has somehow modified
>     app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php, creating a
>     hard to track down bug
> - The cookie domain in System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Cookie
>     Management doesn't match the actual site domain.
> - You're using the localhost as your server domain, and using a version
>     of webkit that has trouble/bugs setting cookies for localhost in some
>     situations.
>
> The short term fix is to just delete your cookie for the domain.
>   That's often enough to solve the problem. If it persists, figure out
>   which of the above reasons is the reason for your error, and take
>   steps to address it (fix permissions, etc.)

Comment: have you on holiday ..doing answering on lot of question :)

Comment: @AmitBera no I am in good mood to answer now :) Normally I would be here, but only do moderating most of the time :)

Comment: @AmitBera ha ha same for you :)

Comment: I think both are on holiday @MineshPatel :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with @Rushabh Shah's answer follow these steps

Copy file

> app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/session/abstract/varien.php

to

> app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/session/abstract/varien.php

Go to line number 95 and comment out cookieParams array and and define $cookieParams  as array like below

```
    // session cookie params
    /*$cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
        'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );*/
    $cookieParams = array();
```

This will tempary fix issue with login in google chrome but we still need to find out "why ?"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open admin using chrome ,

1.Open the admin panel first using another browser(like Mozilla).

2.Then go to admin panel  check configuration,
 system->configuration->web->session & cookie management in that the HTTP control set from Yes to No.

3.Then open admin in chrome browser easily.

Hope this will help you.