# Magento, Successful Login Redirects to Login

Tags: admin, magento-1.14, admin-login

When logging in to the admin panel I am redirected to a url such as follows (where 4.2.2.2 is a random value):

```
 http://4.2.2.2/index.php/admin/index/index/key/24633634065368573042cf976992f849244a20c6bd0e364a41cb6962ccb87bef/
```

To be clear, this occurs after a successful login; as opposed to a failure where the failure count is updated for the user in the `admin_user` table.

The install I was working with originally had an issue for logging into the admin section. I reset the password and made the following changes to `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php`:

```
#1 $cookieParams = array(
#2    'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
#3    'path' => $cookie->getPath(),
#4    //'domain' => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
#5    //'secure' => $cookie->isSecure(),
#6    //'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
#7);

#8/*
#9 if (!$cookieParams['httponly']) {
#10    unset($cookieParams['httponly']);
#11    if (!$cookieParams['secure']) {
#12         unset($cookieParams['secure']);
#13         if (!$cookieParams['domain']) {
#14             unset($cookieParams['domain']);
#15            }
#16    }
#17 }
#18
#19 if (isset($cookieParams['domain'])) {
#20     $cookieParams['domain'] = $cookie->getDomain();
#21 }
#22 */
```

Where the commented out lines (4 through 6, and 8 through 22) are the changes. These changes are described in numerous sources related to this issue (and similar admin login issues), such as this: :

[Magento 1.9 Can’t login to admin panel!](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel#)

This corrected the issue for a time; and then it reared its head again. I've cleared the file based sessions; `var/session`. I've cleared the cache; `var/cache`.

Any tips on solving this?

Comment: You may check the cookie lifetime and if there's a gap between the server's time and your client's time.

Comment: I've checked the cookie lifetime and I know that isn't the issue. I've checked the server time and it reports the UTC time correctly, albiet +0 and my timezone is -5. Is this a possible issue or is this taken into account?

Comment: Depends on your cookie lifetime. If it's lower than 18000 than this might be the cause.

Comment: I changed the cookie lifetime to 18000; cleared the session files and the cache and it did not help.