# Magento 1.9.2.2: Can't login into admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, login, backend

I'm developing on a shop, local, and starting it with

`php -S localhost:3000`

http://localhost:3000 works for me.

But when I want to login into backend, it keeps displaying only the login page.
I also created a new admin user using `n98-magerun`, I've deleted all cookies, and still can't login...

The `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` in core_config_data are also set to `http://localhost:3000`.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you check if your session data is beeing saved and you have correct permissions set to session directory?

Answer (score 3):

**A quick fix**
**=========================================================================**
This is an problem of saving cookie in browser! 
You can overcome this by by coping `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php` to `/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php`.
Then look for the below code on the `/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php`.

```
$cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
        'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );
```

Then comment this lines.. And then try again. You should be able to login on the admin panel.

**Note:** If all folder not exits on the local folder then you need to create those and then paste your file.

Comment: Excellent! With this quickfix it works for me!

Answer (score 2):

There is a issue with sessions.
This only happens when you set "session_save" in "local.xml" to "db".
If you try with the option "files" there are no problems.

Error.

> Recoverable Error: session_regenerate_id(): Failed to create(read)
>   session ID: user (path: /var/lib/php/sessions) in
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 492

Answer (score 0):

It should have to work on firefox.
If you are using chrome please specify your system ip instead of localhost.

Comment: with firefox it does not work either

Answer (score 0):

Try to login with chrom incognito. to use incognito press ctrl+shift+n. 
if it's stary on login page again, just try to reload the page a couple of times. 
This is hapening to me a couple of times on different websites. 
Also I recomand you to take a look in that solution 
[Magento 1.9 Can’t login to admin panel!](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel)

Hope it helps you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all solution but none of them worked for me!
Final solution was to change the location of session store. In my case session were stored in the database that was causing a problem. 
I have changed it to save session in the Filesystem. And it worked perfectly.