# Magento 1: Back-end Log-out?

Tags: magento-1.9

I tried to change the password but it not working.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 1.9.2.2: Can't login into admin panel](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112881/magento-1-9-2-2-cant-login-into-admin-panel)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: VarienForm is not defined

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons

1. Check in database, if your admin account is inactive by this query

   `SELECT user_id, username, is_active FROM admin_user WHERE username='YOUR_USER_Name'`
2. You forgot your password. If you forgot your password then Magento will show same error as it is showing now. You need to reset your password. You can do it from database. Run this command

   `SELECT MD5(123456)`

You will get the value like this: `e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e`

Then run this command on your database

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password='e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e' WHERE username='YOUR_USER_Name' LIMIT 1
```

After this you can login with your username and password would be '`123456`'

Comment: I tried many solutions: change the password, create a new account, but it doesn't seem to work. And I think it's error from cookies

Comment: @NewBie if you think its cookies have you tried from a different browser or in incognito mode?

Comment: Yes, i tried from a different browser or in incognito mode but it still not working.