# Problemns Login in Admin Panel

Tags: magento2

i just started using magento co and installed the latest version in my local machine. But something is wrong with it, i view  the front-End of the store but when i try to login in Admin Panel, it doesnt go to the dashboard, and doesnt even give me a response. So i went to check in my console network and i notice a "302 Found". (using chrome)

The strangest thing is when i use for example the firefox browser,i cant even view the admin login page, it gives me redirections problems.

I dont understand what is wrong, doest someone have a similar situation?

Configuration and details:

Site url: magendo.development

Site url admin: magendo.development/admin

Magento ver 2.0.5 Vanilla Instalation

PHP 5.6.3 Apache 2.4

Local Host;

Windows 10

VHost Configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    Define MAGENTO_ROOT "c:/development/magento"

    DocumentRoot ${MAGENTO_ROOT}

    ServerName magendo.development

    RewriteEngine On
    #LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8

    <Directory ${MAGENTO_ROOT}>
        AllowOverride all
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you check your admin uri is proper?

Comment: Try: **ServerName localhost**

Answer (score 1):

This is the link where all the required solution

1. [Magento 1.9 Can’t login to admin panel!](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel)

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in *\Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\Proxy*. There are *$subject* & *$isShared* properties in this class but method *__sleep()* uses *'_subject'* & *'_isShared'* as names for the props. Just rename props in the *__sleep()* method (file `vendor/magento/framework/Translate/Inline/Proxy.php`):

```
public function __sleep()
{
    # return ['_subject', '_isShared'];
    return ['subject', 'isShared'];
}
```

(the same quest & this answer on [Magento Connect](https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/Problems-Login-in-Admin-Panel/m-p/35978#U35978))

Comment: The bug exists in version 100.0.7 of the "magento/framework" module. This issue is appear when composer is used for installation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check first your `app/etc/env.php` file at top,

```
'backend' => 
  array (
    'frontName' => 'admin_m2sdq',
  )
```

Here **`frontName`** value is used for adminpanel url,

your admin url like,

```
http://127.0.0.1/magento2/admin_m2sdq
```

If you can access with admin and your url is changed at that time its create issue like redirection or page not found.

So suggestion is check `env.php` file and set proper url to access admin.