# Can't login to admin page with no errors

Tags: magento-1.9

I tried with this [way](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel) but it doesn't work.

What causes this problem occur?
Because after one month installation, everything is okay and suddenly this is happened.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think Are you use chrome browser .
open this from Mozilla . sometimes chrome not able to save session data .
Are you using localhost ?
change url from localhost to 127.0.0.1 At core_config_data table from database.
```

Comment: I think this is enough to solve your problem . post answer for better use . and like/accept answer .

Answer (score -2):

Clean up your cache under /var/cache and delete log files under /var/log

Comment: I could understand if you advised to delete var/session (still bad advise because everybody looses their cart and login), but deleting var/log is plain stupid. Don't do that!

Comment: @fschmengler opt didn't mention `var/session` folder. `var/log` total agree with you