# Customer Login issue

Tags: login, customer-account, customer-session, magento-1.9.2.1

I have magento multi (multiwebsite) store like `www.example.com` and customer login is working fine here.

My other store Url is `shop.example.com` and when customer try to login after registration on shop.example.com not able to login.

Comment: What are your cookie settings in *System > Configuration > Web"? The cookie domain should be www.example.com for the first store and shop.example.com for the second store

Comment: `Cookie Lifetime: 3600` for both stores

Comment: Cookie lifetime doesn't matter much, there are more settings. Check cookie path and cookie domain.

Comment: cookie path and cookie domain are blank currently for both store

Comment: Then please set the domain as described above.

Comment: these changes stop me to login in admin also. So I have make changes in verien.php to login again as describe here [http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel]