# Invalid Form Key, Please refresh the page - Admin Panel

Tags: magento-1.9

My issue is that I can't login to the **admin panel**, I know that this is already asked, and I have tried:

1. Clear cache and sessions,browser cookies.
2. **web/cookie/cookie_domain** and **web/cookie/cookie_path** clear in the table **core_config_data**
3. i will check the session path its correct

but still same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible causes :

- Local computer time vs. server time mismatch, causing instant cookie invalidation. Make sure your server time is correct.
- Incorrect permissions on var/session, preventing session files from being saved
- Incorrect configuration of database/redis/other session storage, preventing saving of session values
- A module is instantiating sessions to early, preventing the correct session names from being set
- You're a developer using multiple URLs and have multiple cookie domains
- Another developer has somehow modified app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php, creating a hard to track down bug
- The cookie domain in `System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Cookie Management` doesn't match the actual site domain.
- You're using the localhost as your server domain, and using a version of webkit that has trouble/bugs setting cookies for localhost in some situations.

The short term fix is to just delete your cookie for the domain. That's often enough to solve the problem. If it persists, figure out which of the above reasons is the reason for your error.

- Changing '`Use HTTP only`' to '**No**' in 'System->Configuration->Web->Session Cookies Management' of the 'Web' settings.

[Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel)

Comment: I am new to magento.Explain what i need to do @Prince

Comment: Where have you this issue ?

Comment: During admin login i have this issue

Comment: are you using Chrome browser ?

Comment: Yes and also Mozilla

Comment: Please, look my update

Comment: @Prince In my case successfully log in, then the message shown "Invalid Secret Key. Please refresh the page.", may i know why i have received this error?

Answer (score 3):

New versions of Magento like 1.9 require to have in phtml file

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

to prevent CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) attacks.

Answer (score 3):

Instant solved problem with:

```
    $ n98 config:delete web/cookie/cookie_domain
     // make sure dir in the system and correct permission tmp/session
    <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
    <session_save_path><![CDATA[/tmp/session]]></session_save_path>
```

Greetings from Posadas 3300, Argentina

Answer (score 1):

Open DB and execute below two queries, DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_domain'; DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_path';

now open /app/etc/local.xml and place below two lines,

session_save

session_save ![CDATA[files]] /session_save

```
    session_save_path ![CDATA[/tmp/session]] /session_save_path
```

with >< symbol