# Magento 1.9 backend dies

Tags: magento-1.9

When I login, the top 'Magento Admin Panel' logo is shown but nothing below it.  There are no JS errors in the console.  When I view source, this is the bottom of the code:

```
<div class="nav-bar">
<!-- menu start -->
```

After that the page stops.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: This question may have been answered before, please review.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel

Answer (score 1):

This is where your code is being blocked:

```
<?php echo $this->getMenuLevel($this->getMenuArray()); ?>
```

Most probably `$this->getMenuArray()` is generating the error. Inside `getMenuArray()` there is `_buildMenuArray()` function which is responsible for creating menu nodes. My guess is that there is ACL permission admin access problem which is blocking creating the nodes. Try to manually delete all cache, session and locks data from /var/cache, /var/session and /var/locks to see if that solves the problem.

Comment: I deleted those 3 cache but it's still doing it.  I logged out and tried different browsers.  Page source still gets cut off at the same spot.  Anything else I can try?

Comment: Also, when I comment out <?php echo $this->getMenuLevel($this->getMenuArray()); ?>, the rest of the page loads, so it is definitely something with that function.

Comment: Check your app/etc/local.xml file to see if the session is being saved on files or database. If the session data is stored in database then truncate core_session table.

Comment: it's set as <![CDATA[files]]>

Comment: Did you check the file permissions on /var/session?