# Magento admin panel login issues

Tags: magento-1.9

My website is live website and its working fine until yesterday I am unable to access admin panel. I dont know how to fix it. Even after login it stays on the same login page 
[image]

I tried all possible following solutions, none working, My site is on cloudflair

**I updated the**

> app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php

```
// session cookie params
    $cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath() //,
    // 'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
    //  'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
   //   'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );
```

**edit these setting to null as well**
[image]

error log

```
[07-Nov-2017 05:46:23 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'File '/home/abc/public_html/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/300x400/85e4522595efc69f496374d01ef2bf13/6/4' does not exists.' in /home/abc/public_html/lib/Varien/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php:96
Stack trace:
#0 /home/abc/public_html/get.php(205): Varien_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http->send('/home/abc/...')
#1 /home/abc/public_html/get.php(165): sendFile('/home/abc/...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home/abc/public_html/lib/Varien/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php on line 96
[07-Nov-2017 05:46:27 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'File '/home/abc/public_html/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/300x400/85e4522595efc69f496374d01ef2bf13/8/g' does not exists.' in /home/abc/public_html/lib/Varien/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php:96
Stack trace:
#0 /home/abc/public_html/get.php(205): Varien_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http->send('/home/abc/...')
#1 /home/abc/public_html/get.php(165): sendFile('/home/abc/...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home/abc/public_html/lib/Varien/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php on line 96
```

Comment: undo the changes and try to login from different browser

Comment: that was the first thing i did its not even working on firefox

Comment: clear browser cookies, try in private window, delete cache and session from var folder and try once.....

Comment: did that still no

Comment: @SanyaZahid can you check system.log and excepton log files in var/log folder...... also this link may give some hint : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel

Comment: added error logs in description