# Customer login is not working before 24 hours of registration in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, login

I have a Magento 1.9 site and the customer login is not working **before 24 hours of registration**. Before 24 hours of registration, when I try to login with correct credentials it redirects me to the **homepage** and if I enter incorrect credentials then it shows incorrect credentials error.

Comment: Try this URL https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel/26083#26083